# golang: Convert date with time to seconds

Tags: go

If I have date format: "1/_2/2006, 15:04:05"

How to I convert the entire date to seconds. Is there a golang time method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice little package on GitHub to abstract the format matching part of `Parse` (it requires you provide a string to explain the format of your date); https://github.com/araddon/dateparse

You can just use `ParseAny` to get a `time.Time{}` call it `ts` then `ts.Unix` to get seconds. I would recommend it since `Parse` itself is extremely sensitive to it's input.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `time.Parse` and then call `Unix` on the result:

- https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse
- https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix